# bootstrap button and link it to another page with the row data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

There's a table that is listed out from SQL and I have added a button on every row which I want it to link to another page.

The problem is that I would like that button to open up the correct row of data.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumpbotron">
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr class="success">
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Subject</td>
                <td>Details</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>ticket id</td>
                <td>Actions</td>



            </tr>

        </thead>
<?php       

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))//while look to fetch the              result and store in a array $row.  
        {  

            $date=$row[2];
            $subject=$row[3];
            $detail=$row[4];
            $status=$row[5];
            $tickid=$row[0];

        ?> 
        <form method="post">
        <tbody method="post">

            <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($date); ?></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($subject); ?></td>
            <td class="col-sm-2"><?php print_r($detail); ?> </td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><?php print_r($status); ?></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><?php echo $tickid ; ?></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><a href="detail.php" name="submit"     id="submit"class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Details</td>

        </tbody>
        </form>

        <?php } ?> 
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the $tickid on your detail.php using $_GET['id'], in addition the user can copy the URI and share your current row's details.

```
<a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo $tickid; ?>" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
```

Comment: hi, i tried using GET and echo it. but i cannot get the tickid.

Comment: If you are using chrome press ctrl+shift+i and make sure your anchor tag's href is detail.php?id=something.